# Saying "aamin" after imam finishes surah Fatiha

Tags: salat

When Imam finishes recitation of Surah Fatiha, we should say "aamin" in a loud voice or silently ?

Comment: See this http://islamqa.org/hanafi/qibla-hanafi/35121

Answer (score 2, accepted):

التأمين بعد الفراغ من الفاتحة في الصلاة سنة للإمام والمأموم ، يجهران به في صلاة الجهر ، ويسران به في صلاة السر
وهو سنة أيضا عقب قراءة الفاتحة خارج الصلاة .

Saying Amiin after the Fatiha when praying is a sunnah for both the imam and for the musallin , you say it Jahran (in a loud voice) when in a salat al jamaa (praying with people ) or during salat al jahr (sobh-maghreb-ishaa), and Serran (in a lower voice) when praying  alone or during salat a sser (dohr-asr) and saying it is also a sunnah after reading it outside prayers...

but why saying amiin in surat al fatihaa and not in many other ? just why ?
well because in the surah there is a duaa "ٱهْدِنَا ٱلصِّرَٰطَ ٱلْمُسْتَقِيمَ صِرَٰطَ ٱلَّذِينَ أَنْعَمْتَ عَلَيْهِمْ غَيْرِ ٱلْمَغْضُوبِ عَلَيْهِمْ وَلَا ٱلضَّآلِّينَ" " Guide us to the straight path.
7. The path of those You have blessed, not of those against whom there is anger, nor of those who are misguided." usually after a duaa we say amiin

Comment: Jazak Allah Khair for your help.

Comment: anytime  (y) (y)